# Включать ли jQuery в коммит?

Tags: jquery, git, npm

В проекте библиотеки типа jQuery, jQueryUI, bootstrap помещаю в папку lib.
Какая правильная практика коммита такого проекта?
Нужно ли вносить в коммит папку lib?

Или, возможно, лучше инсталлировать jQuery и прочие библиотеки через npm в папку node_modules, включать node_modules в gitignore, и восстанавливать содержимое node_modules через npm install?

Comment: `node_modules`, если используется, обязательно должен быть в gitignore, а использовать его или нет — личное дело каждого по-моему, я не использую)

Comment: Это понятно. Вопрос в том, какая best practice для коммитов папок с используемыми сторонними библиотеками (типа jquery). Их включают в коммит или нет?

Comment: Определенно НЕТ! Все данные о зависимостях лежать в package.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**jQuery** и пр. библиотеки - это внешне зависимости. Включат их в свой проект нужно используя **менеджер зависимостей**. То есть сама зависимость в ваш репозиторий не попадает, а попадает только ссылка на нее.

При сборке проекта **менеджер зависимостей** найдет нужный артефакт(ы) и подключит его(их) к вашему проекту.

Есть много **менеджеров зависимостей**, вот некоторые

- [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/)
- [Bower](https://bower.io/)
- [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/)
- [jspm](http://jspm.io/)
- [volo](http://volojs.org/)
- [RingoJS](https://github.com/grob/rp/wiki)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие менеджеры зависимостей сейчас рекомендуются к использованию?

Comment: на подобный вопрос сложно ответить объективно. так как каждый хвалит свой любимый менеджер и ругает остальные. я добавлю в ответ список, но не будут давать им оценку.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Дополнительный вопросы по этому поводу.
В проекте backend реализован на Node.js. Управление backend-модулями, естественно, производится при помощи npm.  
Правильно ли будет использовать npm еще и для управления frontend библиотеками?  В этом случае frontend библиотеки будут попадать в ту же папку node_modules что и backend-модули, будут прописаны в одном файле package.json c backend-модулями.  Это нормальная практика тогда и backend и frontend зависимости попадают в одну и ту же папку node_modules, а ссылки на них в один и тот же файл package.json?

Comment: да. так можно делать. но будет лучше в боевом режиме использовать **CDN** версии библиотек.

Comment: Т.е. CDN предпочтительнее, чем расположение библиотек на сервере приложения?
И в этом случае вообще отпадает необходимость хранить где-либо в проекте frontend-зависимости.

Comment: в боевом режиме да - предпочтительней. но хранить зависимости все равно необходимо.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ @Mikhail Vaysman.  
Извините за, возможно, очень дилетантский вопрос.  
Я знаю только один способ загрузки frontend-библиотек из CDN, это прописывание ссылок на них в теге script. В этом случае это и есть как бы ссылки на внешние зависимости.  
Где правильно хранить ссылки на внешние зависимости в случае использования CDN?

Comment: Мне кажется, нам нужен канонический вопрос о том, что такое зависимости и как их правильно версионировать.